# NetLogo: ask link-neighbors for a tick-counter value

Tags: social-networking, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

At the moment I am working on an agent-based model about successful innovation diffusion in social networks. So far I am a newbie in agent-based-modeling and programing.

The main idea is to model social learning among farmers, hence the agents decision to adopt an innovation mainly depends on his personal network, meaning that if he is well connected and his neighbours are using the innovation successfully, he will more likely adopt than if he is located remotely in the network.

Beside the network related arguments about social learning,  I would like to implement a time dimension, for example the longer the neighbors of an agent use the innovation successfully, the more likely the agent will adopt the innovation as well. But this is exactly the point where I am stuck right at the moment. My goal is to implement the following argument. The Pseudo Code looks like the following so far.

**1) a turtles-own tick counter**
...

```
ask turtles 
[ 
 ifelse [adopted? = true]
    [set ime-adopted time-adopted + 1] [set time-adopted 0]
    ]
```

...

**2)** In a second precedure each agent should check how long his neighbours use this innovation (in terms of "check time-adopted of neighbors").

```
ask turtles with [not adopted?]
[ 
[ask link-neigbhors with [adopted?] 
    [...*(Here I dont know how to ask for the time adopted value)*]
;the agent will then sum up all values he got from his neighbors from "time-adopted"

set time-neighbors-adopted [sum all "time-adopted" values of neighbors]
]

;The agent will then implement these values into his personal utility       
;function which determines if he adopts the innovation or not 

set utility utiltiy + 0.3 * time-neighbors-adopted
]
```

Many thanks for your help and advice.

Kind regards,

Moritz

Comment: King-Ink's answer will get you what you want under your approach. However, there is no need for each turtle to have a tick counter. Instead, just have a variable (perhaps when-adopted) and, as part of the procedure where a turtle adopts the procedure, simply include the line `set when-adopted ticks`. Then time since adopted is just `ticks - when-adopted` and you don't need to keep incrementing it. The reported `ticks` is built in and available to all entities in NetLogo.

Comment: Thank you for this tip and for a further procedure of solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the sum of time the neighbors have adopted the innovation you only need one line because Netlogo is amazing.

```
set time-neighbors-adopted sum [time-adopted] of link-neighbors with [adopted?]
```

like that

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Got the question solved, the procedure suggested by you fits quite well.